# UITableView editing is set to NO after reloading table

Tags: uitableview, reloaddata, ios8

In iOS 8, when I call [tableView reloadData] after deleting/moving rows, it seems the property editing of my tableView will be set back to NO (I set my tableview's editing = YES before) all the time. It is really annoyed I have to set editing property to YES after reloading my tableview. Is it a bug of iOS 8?  I would be appreciate if anyone has a work around to keep the editing property unchanged.

Updated:
Even I set editing to YES again, my tableView can not be edited anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. The following method of `UITableViewCell` does give editing as "YES"

```
(void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
```

I have a check inside this method:

```
if ([NSStringFromClass([view class]) rangeOfString: @"Reorder"].location != NSNotFound)
```

which seems to be working when the table is created for the first time. However, it does not work when table gets reloaded.

Comment: It seems a bug in iOS 8 beta version. I've asked for Developer Technical Support, and they said that it was beta/seed software. Therefore I had to submit a bug report.

Comment: Well, now it is a bug in iOS 8 Live version. Great